# Is there an equivalent for .checked when using click buttons instead of radio buttons

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have a functioning HTA that uses radio buttons and I am able to use `.checked` to find which button is clicked.  I am having a go at re-writing my HTA to use ordinary buttons but I am unable to come up with an equivalent command that works.

This is my radio button logic that works fine:

```
For Each objButton in document.Uber.RadioOption
  If objButton.Checked Then
    strFilexl = fpath & cname & "_" & "PC_" & objButton.Value & ".xlsx"
  end if
Next
```

This is what I was hoping to use but I have not been able to find an equivalent command to insert in the code for a button check:

```
set ColButton = document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
For Each strButton In colButton
  if strButton.xxxxxx then
      strFilexl = fpath & cname & "_" & "PC_" & strButton.Value & ".xlsx"   
  End If
  strButton.Disabled = True
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular buttons don't have a state, so you need an additional element for storing a state. A hidden input element is customary for this type of thing.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
     ID="objTest"
     APPLICATIONNAME="Test"
>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
Sub ToggleFoo
  FooClicked.Value = Not FooClicked.Value
End Sub
</script>

<body>
<p>
<input type="hidden" id="FooClicked" value="0">
<input type="submit" value="Foo" OnClick="ToggleFoo">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```